# Identifying T1 and T2 in the Claperyon equation

Tags: vapor-pressure

Is there a way to identify T1 and T2 in the two point form of the claperyon equation?

I suspect that the greater temperature is T1 and the smaller temperature is T2.

Comment: $T_1$ simply corresponds to $P_1$, same with $T_2$ and $P_2$.

It is not a matter of smaller/greater. $T_1$ is *the temperature at* $P_1$